# Split, re-arrange and concatenate a string in a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to re-arrange a string based on the length of its comma-separated lists. For example, the following string contains four commas, we split the string delimited by comma; we get four lists. Now we ignore those lists whose length (word count) is less than or equal to four and merge them to subsequent list whose word count or length is more than four.

With the following code I have separated the lists as per their length, but having trouble figuring out how to concatenate them back so that get the result that looks like:

```
['In fact, a 2016 study published in the journal Current Biology shows that our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity', 'resulting in a decline in weight loss, even a reversal, after a few months']
```

Code:

```
import re


string = "In fact, a 2016 study published \
in the journal Current Biology shows that \
our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity, \
resulting in a decline in weight loss, \
even a reversal, after a few months"

pattern = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")

small = []
big = []

for x in pattern.split(string):

    if 1 <= len(x.split()) <= 4:
        small.append(x)
    else:      
        big.append(x)

print small = ['In fact', 'even a reversal', 'after a few months']
print big = ['a 2016 study published in the journal Current Biology shows that our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity', 'resulting in a decline in weight loss']
```

Here is a working solution to my own problem:

```
string = "In fact, a 2016 study published \
in the journal Current Biology shows that \
our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity, \
resulting in a decline in weight loss, \
even a reversal, after a few months"
listy= [x.strip() for x in string.split(',')] 
newstring= []

for segment in listy:

    if listy[len(listy)-1] != segment:

        if len(segment.split(' ')) > 4:
            newstring.append(segment+"&&")
        else:
            newstring.append(segment+",")

    else:

        newstring.append(segment)

newlisty= [x.strip() for x in (' '.join(newstring)).split('&&')]
print newlisty
```

Thank you everyone who have taken time to answer my question.

Comment: What's your rule to concatenate the `small` and the `big` list?

Comment: big already is your answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "In fact, a 2016 study published \
    in the journal Current Biology shows that \
    our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity, \
    resulting in a decline in weight loss, \
    even a reversal, after a few months"
listy=string.split(',') #split string by comma
newstring=[]
for segment in listy:
    if len(list(list(filter(None, segment.split(' ')))))>4: #sort out short strings
           newstring.append(segment) #add segment to the list
print(newstring)
```

And the result is:

```
   [' a 2016 study published     in the journal Current Biology shows that     our bodies adjust to higher levels of activity', '     resulting in a decline in weight loss']
```

Comment: The OP want a list. Your answer return a string.

Comment: I followed these guidelines: "For example, the following string contains four commas, we split the string delimited by comma; we get four lists. Now we ignore those lists whose length (word count) is less than or equal to four and merge them to subsequent list whose word count or length is more than four."

Comment: Please the second paragraph of the OP.

Comment: The author know how to split the string and group by word count of the segment. What he want to know is how to concatenate the two list(`small` & `big`) back to the list he provide. But he don't provide the concatenate rule.